# How to validate field in inline entity form referenced field

Tags: nodes

I have created field "Referenced"  which is entity reference field of other content type. Also this field have inline entity form functionality means its giving two button "add new node" and "and existing node"

Once we clicked on "add new node", publication content type node form will open. i want to make field_author entity reference field inside the inline entity form

Answer (score 0):

Inline entity form only makes the *connection* to some structure and *displays* it, it doesn't change it. In your case the Inline entity form is showing the Create node form of a certain type (you haven't mentioned which type is in your case), but you can't change the structure through the Inline entity form.

If you want to add a User reference field to that node type you have to go through Structure > Content types > [Your type] > Manage fields.

There you can add a new field (or use an existing one if it makes sense to your structure) of the type Reference > User.

Once you add that field when you go to created nodes that reference that node type through the Inline entity form, you will see the User reference field among the fields after clicking on "Add new node".

Comment: Thanks for reply . That I got . But when i click on "Add new node" , node form will open , and in that form i want journal field required. But this field is also inline entity form